# Red circle appears as cursor

Tags: interface

When LMB clicking the mouse is replaced by a red circle. This unfortunate behaviour occasionally disappears.

[image]

How can I get rid of that?
(I can't connect nodes properly, because the cursor changes.)

Comment: Looks like *Erase* of the grease pencil. However, this should not appear in this context. Also I can't confirm, works as expected on linux. What Add-ons are enabled?

Comment: @poor Thank you, you are correct it was the eraser. I have already added an answer. The pen was to close to the graphics tablet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Few minutes later.]

That is the Grease Pencil Eraser.

Make sure there are no other inputs except for the mouse. In this case there was a graphics tablet with the pen in near proximity.